# R - extract Rd format from documentation in comment header?

Tags: r

Are there any good examples of R documentation embedded into the function header comments and extracted to Rd via a parser?  See http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Documentation for examples in other languages.  My preference is to do all of my documentation in the function header comments.  Perhaps there is an already-built parser that can generate the Rd from the comments and a standard comments grammar that I can leverage?

Comment: I found this: http://inlinedocs.r-forge.r-project.org/

Comment: Also this: http://roxygen.org/

Comment: It seems like you searched after you posted the question; it's usually better to do things in the opposite order.  Searching StackOverflow for "[r] documentation" probably would have answered your question.  [rseek](http://www.rseek.org) is another good search method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [roxygen](http://roxygen.org/), which is probably exactly what you're looking for. For some examples, see [the documentation vignette](http://roxygen.org/roxygen.pdf).